# Spliting string into two by comma using python

Tags: python, regex, split, hex

I have following data in a list and it is a hex number,

['aaaaa955554e']

I would like to split this into ['aaaaa9,55554e'] with a comma.

I know how to split this when there are some delimiters between but how should i do for this case?

Thanks

Comment: What are the criteria for splitting? (In half?) Where did the `e` go?

Comment: Please elobrate little more. where exactly you want to split.

Comment: Edited. I would like to split and leave in the same list. Thanks

Comment: `txt = ['aaaaa955554e']` and `txt[0] = txt[0][:6]+','+txt[0][6:]` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what I think you are looking for:

```
yourlist = ['aaaaa955554e']
new_list = [','.join([x[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(x), 6)]) for x in yourlist]
```

It will put a comma at every sixth character in each item in your list. (I am assuming you will have more than just one item in the list, and that the items are of unknown length. Not that it matters.)

Answer (score 0):

i assume you wanna split into every 6th character

using regex

```
import re
lst = ['aaaaa955554e']
newlst = re.findall('\w{6}', lst[0])
# ['aaaaa9', '55554e']
```

Using list comprehension, this works for multiple items in lst

```
lst = ['aaaaa955554e']
newlst = [item[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(a[0]),6) for item in lst]
# ['aaaaa9', '55554e']
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a regular expression substitution as follows:

```
import re    

print re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+\d)(.*?)', r'\1,\2', 'aaaaa955554e', count=1)
```

Giving you:

```
aaaaa9,55554e
```

This splits after seeing the first digit.